# Contradictory behavior in C to C# array marshalling

Tags: c#, c++, pinvoke, marshalling

I have two example with almost same code. I can retrieve data of one from C# and I failed to have correct data for an other. Here they are:

**Works good**

C++ Part:

```
__declspec(dllexport) void** enumerateDevices(int *dIsize){
    Array<DeviceInfo> dIArray;
    Framewoek::enumerateDevices(&dIArray);
    *dIsize = dIArray.getSize();
    DeviceInfo dP[255];
    for (int i = 0; i < dIArray.getSize(); i++)
        dP[i] = dIArray[i];
    void* p = dP;
    return &p;
}
```

C# Part:

```
    [DllImport("Wrapper.dll")]
    static extern IntPtr enumerateDevices(out int devicesSize);
    public static DeviceInfo[] EnumerateDevices()
    {
        int devicesSize;
        IntPtr arrayPointer = enumerateDevices(out devicesSize);
        IntPtr[] array = new IntPtr[devicesSize];
        Marshal.Copy(arrayPointer, array, 0, devicesSize);
        DeviceInfo[] arrayObjects = new DeviceInfo[devicesSize];
        for (int i = 0; i < devicesSize; i++)
            arrayObjects[i] = new DeviceInfo(array[i]);
        return arrayObjects;
    }
```

**Don't works as expected**

C++ Part:

```
__declspec(dllexport) void** SensorInfo_getSupportedVideoModes(SensorInfo* si, int *dIsize){
    const Array<VideoMode>& dIArray = si->getSupportedVideoModes();
    *dIsize = dIArray.getSize();
    VideoMode dP[255];
    for (int i = 0; i < dIArray.getSize(); i++)
        dP[i] = dIArray[i];
    void* p = dP;
    return &p;
}
```

C# Part:

```
    [DllImport("Wrapper.dll")]
    static extern IntPtr SensorInfo_getSupportedVideoModes(IntPtr objectHandler, out int arraySize);
    public VideoMode[] getSupportedVideoModes()
    {
        int arraySize;
        IntPtr arrayPointer = SensorInfo_getSupportedVideoModes(this.Handle, out arraySize);
        IntPtr[] array = new IntPtr[arraySize];
        Marshal.Copy(arrayPointer, array, 0, arraySize);
        VideoMode[] arrayObjects = new VideoMode[arraySize];
        for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++)
            arrayObjects[i] = new VideoMode(array[i]);
        return arrayObjects;
    }
```

As you can see I just want pointer of objects. But second example give me invalid pointers. I don't know why. It is a big library I am trying to create a .net wrapper and everything works good except this function.

Note: Array<> is a template class containing two field, size and array and couple of methods.

---

*Edit: I know it is a local variable (Even VS give me warning), but why first one works then?!

---

*Edit 2:

I solved second problem using @JefferyThomas answer. Its look like this now and has no problem:
C++ side:

```
__declspec(dllexport) void* SensorInfo_getSupportedVideoModes(SensorInfo* si, int *dIsize){
    const Array<VideoMode>& dIArray = si->getSupportedVideoModes();
    *dIsize = dIArray.getSize();
    VideoMode** dP = new VideoMode*[255];
    for (int i = 0; i < dIArray.getSize(); i++)
        dP[i] = const_cast<VideoMode*>(&(dIArray[i]));
    return dP;
}
__declspec(dllexport) void SensorInfo_destroyVideoModesArray(VideoMode** dP){
    delete[] dP;
}
```

Currently I have problem with changing my first function like what @JefferyThomas suggested. Let's take a look to code then I will tell u where is the problem.
C++ Side:

```
__declspec(dllexport) void** Framework_enumerateDevices(int *dIsize){
    Array<DeviceInfo> dIArray;
    Framework::enumerateDevices(&dIArray);
    *dIsize = dIArray.getSize();
    DeviceInfo* dP = new DeviceInfo[255];
    for (int i = 0; i < dIArray.getSize(); i++)
        dP[i] = dIArray[i];
    void** p = new void*;
    *p = dP;
    return p;
}
__declspec(dllexport) void Framework_destroyDevicesArray(void **p){
    DeviceInfo *dP = (DeviceInfo *)*p;
    //delete [] dP;
    delete p;
}
```

C# Side:

```
    [DllImport("Wrapper.dll")]
    static extern IntPtr Framework_enumerateDevices(out int devicesSize);
    [DllImport("Wrapper.dll")]
    static extern IntPtr Framework_destroyDevicesArray(IntPtr arrayPointer);
    public static DeviceInfo[] EnumerateDevices()
    {
        int devicesSize;
        IntPtr arrayPointer = Framework_enumerateDevices(out devicesSize);
        IntPtr[] array = new IntPtr[devicesSize];
        Marshal.Copy(arrayPointer, array, 0, devicesSize);
        DeviceInfo[] arrayObjects = new DeviceInfo[devicesSize];
        for (int i = 0; i < devicesSize; i++)
            arrayObjects[i] = new DeviceInfo(array[i]);
        Framework_destroyDevicesArray(arrayPointer);
        return arrayObjects;
    }
```

And problems:

1. I cant keep "delete [] dP" in destroy function. It not just delete array, but delete data as well.
2. I can only have first pointer (first item of array) correctly. Other pointers are all incorrect. I don't know why. Tried changing DeviceInfo to array of pointers instead of array of object directly (like second function) and still no success.

Currently I think it is because of Array<> class which dispose and destroy everything.

---

Edit 3: I found solution for first problem my-self. Thanks Jeff for putting me in correct direction.

Comment: Unless `DeviceInfo dP[255]` is defined `static`, you lost your pointer. This will not work in any language...

Comment: You're returning the address of a local!!! NEVER A GOOD THING!

Comment: Are you asking a new question in your edit?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, It is about first question. I told I failed to use your suggestion. If it was your reason for giving me down I think you better read whole question before doing that.

Comment: I've not suggested anything. I'm just trying to understand the question. I this your edit is unfair. It does appear to ask a new question.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, from "your" I mean "Jeffery Thomas". He told me to use delete to release resources, I said it destroy data as well. And ...

Comment: But now you are asking us to debug something else. And we don't have all the info. Jeffrey answered your question. I think you should accept, and treat the next problem as distinct. I don't understand why you have double pointer. Single pointer is enough. I don't see why you allocate 255 elements. Why are you hardcoding that. And your two points at the very end of the edit are imprecise. What do you mean by "delete data as well"? And what is point 2 about?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, Yeah actually I can remove one of pointers. Code was different before. But now it is not necessary. First problem is that delete[] remove objects too (objects of array), lets say array[0] destroy and this mean no data on C# side. This suppose to delete only array but it delete data as well. Second point is about returned data in C#, currently I have only array[0] on C# side no matter how big is array, other pointers are incorrect (array[1] etc..). Jeff answer is of course correct answer but it didn't work here. I just want to know why his answer don't work.

Comment: Currently I think it is because of Array<> class which dispose and destroy everything. It is not new. It is about same function and same problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem here is you are returning a stack variable. This is a bad idea.

Both `VideoMode dP[255];` and `DeviceInfo dP[255];` are destroyed when the function returns. It just so happens that memory has not been overwritten in the first case, you are not so lucky in the second case.

In the past I've allocated from the heap and provided a second releaseXXXX method to free that memory up.

```
__declspec(dllexport) void** enumerateDevices(int *dIsize){
    Array<DeviceInfo> dIArray;
    Framewoek::enumerateDevices(&dIArray);
    *dIsize = dIArray.getSize();
    DeviceInfo *dP = new DeviceInfo[255];
    for (int i = 0; i < dIArray.getSize(); i++)
        dP[i] = dIArray[i];
    void** p = new void*;
    *p = dP;
    return p;
}

__declspec(dllexport) void releaseEnumerateDevices(void **p){
    DeviceInfo *dP = (DeviceInfo *)*p;
    delete [] dP;
    delete p;
}
```

C#

```
    [DllImport("Wrapper.dll")]
    static extern IntPtr enumerateDevices(out int devicesSize);
    static extern void releaseEnumerateDevices(IntPtr arrayPointer);
    public static DeviceInfo[] EnumerateDevices()
    {
        int devicesSize;
        IntPtr arrayPointer = enumerateDevices(out devicesSize);
        IntPtr[] array = new IntPtr[devicesSize];
        Marshal.Copy(arrayPointer, array, 0, devicesSize);
        DeviceInfo[] arrayObjects = new DeviceInfo[devicesSize];
        for (int i = 0; i < devicesSize; i++)
            arrayObjects[i] = new DeviceInfo(array[i]);
        releaseEnumerateDevices(arrayPointer);
        return arrayObjects;
    }
```

Comment: That luck runs out when the pinvoke marshaller obliterates the array with its own stack frames.

Comment: Thanks jeff, Your suggestion solved problem of my second function, but broke my first one. Check first post's edit2 part.

Comment: @SoroushFalahati It looks like you need more sophisticated memory management. I assumed that C# DeviceInfo copied over needed data from C++ DeviceInfo. If the C# DeviceInfo keep a copy of the C++ DeviceInfo pointer, then you will need a way to retain and release each C++ pointers separately. That's not so easy in C#.